# How to retrieve a user profile picture in Liferay

Tags: liferay, profile, image, liferay-6

I want to retrieve a user profile picture. How do i do it? Could you please share a code snippet? Im using Liferay 6.0.6. It has only user.getPortraitId() and no user.getPortraitURL(). So once i get the portrait id inside a JAVA class, what do i do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the implementation of `UserConstants.getPortraitURL(...)` 
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/model/UserConstants.java

On this approach you can get the image url.

If you need the image object, you can load it with `ImageLocalServiceUtil`:

```
        long portraitId = user.getPortraitId();
        Image image = ImageLocalServiceUtil.getImage(portraitId);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton mark :) But how do i get the imagePath to use the getPortraitURL() implementation? Also, once i get the image object, how do i render it?

Comment: imagePath = themeDisplay.getPathImage();

Comment: Hi Mark, if i have to get imagePath using themeDisplay, i would have to be able to get themeDisplay first inside a "JAVA class".... I know that we could do that as follows:                   ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);            But, what does 'request' stand for? Im not using an action class or a servlet to use the "request"

Comment: And what do you use? Is it a portlet?

Comment: Mark i used the ImageLocalServiceUtil as you suggested and it worked... Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two options on rendering portraits in JSP:

```
<img src="<%= themeDisplay.getPathImage()%>  
  /image_gallery?img_id=<%= image.getImageId()%>&t=  
  <%= ImageServletTokenUtil.getToken(image.getImageId())%>">  

<img src="<%= themeDisplay.getPathImage() %>/user_portrait?img_id=<%=id %>">
```

The first approach contains additional security aspect based on security token which you may or may not find relevant to your needs.

Comment: `ImageServletTokenUtil` was replaced by `WebServerServletTokenUtil` as of Liferay 6.1