# How to retrieve User profile picture Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay-6.2

For 6.1 there are solutions available to retrieve user profile pic like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701405/how-to-retrieve-a-user-profile-picture-in-liferay) post, but how to get portrait image in Liferay 6.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier we required to concate some strings to create src, but now Liferay API provide the method i.e.

```
<img src="<%=themeDisplay.getUser().getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)%>" >
```

Thanks.